# Show that :$89|2^{44}-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Show that :$89|2^{44}-1$
Using Fermat's theorem we have:
   $2^{88}\equiv{1}\pmod{89}\ \Rightarrow\ (2^{44}-1)(2^{44}+1)=89k$ , now how can be sure that: $89|2^{44}-1$??

Comment: $89=44\times 2+1$

Comment: Do you know about quadratic residues or primitive roots?

Comment: Unfortunately no!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(2^{11}-1)|2^{44}-1=\left(2^{11}\right)^{4}-1$$
$$89|(2^{11}-1)=2048-1=2047=89\cdot 23$$

Answer (score 3):

$$89\equiv 1\pmod8$$
Thus, $2$ is a quadratic residue $\bmod 89$. So, there exists $a$ such that $a^2\equiv 2 \pmod {89}$. Thus, $2^{44}\equiv a^{88}\equiv 1\pmod{89}$, as desired.